# Box to create a VNC to multiple servers' VGA output and keyboard

Tags: monitoring, hardware, vnc

My boss has ordered me to find a box that we can connect to our 8 servers, so that we can view the VGA output and use the keyboard as if we were sitting directly in front of the server (i.e. see that it is booting), over the network.

A graphical attempt at explaining the solution is:
[image: deployment]

I have searched a lot, but my search is limited by the fact that I do not know what such a box might be called, or if it even exists.

Can anybody help me with the name of such a box or even better, help me find one?

I know that this is a potentially huge security risk, since an attacker might gain access to the box and thereby get almost physical access to the server, but my concerns did not have any impacts on the decision.

Comment: The security risk is typically mitigated by using a separate management LAN, BTW. Enterprise class servers typically have what's called an out-of-band management card built in that can provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use devices like this in our datacenter. They're called [KVM switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) (abbreviation for "keyboard, video and mouse"). The "over the network" part is solved by IPKVM.
I can recommend [ATEN](http://www.aten.com/IP-KVM.htm)

Hope that helps.

Comment: In addition you may benefit from a managed PDU as well allowing you remotely power cycle your servers in case somebody did a shutdown instead of a log off.